# How to align columns when printing on a file in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to print a list with two elements in a file in this format:

```
A:               B
A:               B
```

This is my code

```
file=open("tmp.txt",w)
for i in range(len(List)):
     file.write(List[i][0].ljust(30, ' ')+List[i][1]+'\n')
```

The problem is that if contains a lot of words it messes up the indentation
Example:

```
A:                   B
B
B
```

And I want my output to look like this:

```
A:                   B
                     B
                     B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do something like the following, hope this is what you want
to achieve.

```
import textwrap

List = [
    ["A1", "Some text that you want to write to a file, aligned in\n a column."],
    ["A2", "And this is a shorter text."]]

indention = 30
max_line_length = 30

file=open("tmp.txt", 'w')
for i in range(len(List)):

    out = List[i][0].ljust(indention, ' ')
    cur_indent = 0
    for line in List[i][1].split('\n'):
        for short_line in textwrap.wrap(line, max_line_length):
            out += ' '* cur_indent + short_line.lstrip() + "\n"
            cur_indent = indention

    file.write(out)
```

Output:

```
A1                            Some text that you want to
                              write to a file, aligned in
                              a column.
A2                            And this is a shorter text.
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use format (https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting) to format the string to your liking:

```
>>> List = [['A', 'B'], ['A134563421', 'B'], ['A', 'B']]
>>> for row in List:
   ... print '{0:30}{1}'.format(row[0], row[1])
   ... file.write('{0:30}{1}\n'.format(row[0], row[1]))

A                             B
A134563421                    B
A                             B
```